# How to create/destroy Libvirt's pool when fs is already mounted?

Tags: linux, cloud, libvirt

I use Libvirt to manage storages in cloudover.org cloud. Scripts related to mounting storages use the Libvirt to perform remote mount of nfs storage. Sometimes this storage is already mounted at all nodes (I don't know why) and the Libvirt's pool related to this nfs share is not started.

Do you know how could I mount it by Libvirt? Pool is defined, but not running. Each pool.create fails, because it is mounted:

```
storage_create_failed (internal error: Child process (/bin/mount -t nfs 10.0.0.254:/storage/ /var/lib/cloudOver/storages/NFS01) unexpected exit status 32: mount.nfs: /var/lib/cloudOver/storages/NFS01 is busy or already mounted
```

Also pool.destroy fails, because Libvirt's pool is not running.

Do you know how to fix such problem with Libvirt? The only solution for this time is to manually umount resource at each node and re-create storage pool with Libvirt, but it's a little bit problematic for the administrators of large clusters.

Comment: ps. my distribution is Ubuntu Xenial with Libvirt 1.3.1. Resource is mounted after every reboot. The pool is not marked as autostart